# f = open("text.txt", "w")

Tags: python

Должен создаться файл и туда должна записаться переменная. Во втором классе он должен открыться и передаться в переменную.

```
def items_clicked(self, x):
    self.name = x.text()

    system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    f = open(system + '\\text.txt', 'w')
    f.write(self.name)
    f.close()

def EditPerson(self):
    self.main1 = NewPersonEdit()
    self.main1.show()

class NewPersonEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        f = open(system + "\\text.txt", 'r')
        self.name1 = f.read()
        print(self.name1)
        f.close()
        os.remove(system + "\\text.txt")
        # События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
        # Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.setText(self.name1)
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Professional\\PycharmProjects\\forsasha  V.3(Чисто Учительская версия)\\text.txt':
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/forsasha  V.3(Чисто Учительская версия)/main.py", line 342, in EditPerson
    self.main1 = NewPersonEdit()
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/forsasha  V.3(Чисто Учительская версия)/main.py", line 376, in __init__
    f = open(system + "\\text.txt", 'r')
```

Comment: Файл `text.txt` не существует при попытке открыть его на чтение.

Comment: Так я его создаю `f = open(system + '\\text.txt', 'w')`

Comment: Вы создаете файл в методе `def items_clicked(self, x):` , а ошибка в методе `def __init__(self)` другого класса. Видимо вы пытаетесь читать файл, который еще не создали.

Answer (score 0):

Все работает если вызывать функции в правильной последовательности. Я удалил код не относящийся к вопросу.

```
import os

def items_clicked(self, x):
    name = "Hello World"

    system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    f = open(system + '\\text.txt', 'w')
    f.write(name)
    f.close()

class NewPersonEdit:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        f = open(system + "\\text.txt", 'r')
        self.name1 = f.read()
        print(self.name1)
        f.close()
        os.remove(system + "\\text.txt")


items_clicked(object, None)
system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(os.path.isfile( system + "\\text.txt" ))
npe = NewPersonEdit()
```

\\\\\\\ Output:

```
True
Hello World

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Теперь вопрос, Как мне правильно вызвать, Если это 2 разных окна?

Comment: Это твое приложение. Если вопрос о том, как вызывать методы у объектов PyQt то лучше задать отдельный вопрос. Вообще нужно там где ты создавал эти окна оставить их объекты и вызывать методы.

Comment: Дело в том, почему я начал с файлами копаться. Я не смог перенести `self.name` из одного класса в `self.name1` класса `NewPersonEdit`

Comment: безусловно если эти объекты существуют в одном приложении будет более простой способ передать строку чем файл. Обычно достаточно чтобы NewPersonEdit принимал ее как аргумент конструктора (очевидно строка должна быть определена до этого).